# How to edit nautilus side menu transparency and font color?

Tags: nautilus, desktop-environments, gtk3, transparency

I've been trying to customize my Ubuntu 12.04 Unity desktop.
I am describing what I've done until now to make it easier to understand what is my practical question. Please don't refer to it as too localized.

I like to have my desktop as clean and simple as possible, where the colors of the background image are shared by every other item.
To accomplish this I edited the Radiance theme.
I used My Unity for launcher color and transparency and also for top panel transparency.

[This is how it looks so far](http://ubuntuone.com/7gvKHTERCoVMR6TccInTrh).

Now I am attempting to edit the Nautilus color by following the instructions present in [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/136044/how-do-i-change-the-background-color-of-the-menu-bar).

I want that the Nautilus windows have the same color as the Unity launcher. I used gcolor2 to pick the exact same color and then copy the hex code to the css file. The problem is I don't know if it is possible or how to edit transparency in css files. Besides, I also want to change the font color to white and I don't know how.

[Take a look at an example of a Nautilus window.](http://ubuntuone.com/0qxpHzqLfEFLPdGl2YN6uv)

The color of the side menu is the same as the unity launcher, except the launcher and dash have transparency. Also the font is barely readable and so I would like to change its color if possible.

The question is if it is possible to set transparency on the side menu color and change the font color? If so, how do I do it? I can't find a GUI for that purpose (MyUnity and Ubuntu Tweak don't have) so I assume that it would require editing of css files.